# How can I use domain name as server.name in Dockerized Spring application

Tags: spring, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, application.properties

I'm having a trouble with the Dockerization process of a Spring application. My goal is, that I'd like its server.address propery to represent the domain name of the server it's hosted at, and not the Docker Containers name. What is the correct way to achieve that?

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: compose_mysql_1
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example_password
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  serviceregistry:
    container_name: serviceregistry
    image: portus.arrowhead-ci.tmit.bme.hu/arrowhead/serviceregistry:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./core_system_config/serviceregistry.properties:/serviceregistry/application.properties
      - ./tmit_certs/service_registry.p12:/serviceregistry/service_registry.p12
    ports:
      - 8443:8443

volumes:
  mysql:
    external: true
```

This is my relevant piece of application.properties file:

```
# Service Registry web-server parameters
server.address=serviceregistry
server.port=8443
```

I'd like it to be:

```
# Service Registry web-server parameters
server.address=example.com
server.port=8443
```

In the application.properties if I set it to the container name to the domain name it won't start. I understand, that this is because inside the container "example.com" doesn't mean anything.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-11-14 11:40:34.081  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.s.ServiceRegistryMain              : Starting ServiceRegistryMain v4.1.3 on f75cd8bdc6c5 with PID 6 (/serviceregistry/arrowhead-serviceregistry.jar started by root in /)
2019-11-14 11:40:34.154  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.s.ServiceRegistryMain              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-14 11:40:45.651  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.f.ArrowheadFilter                  : SRAccessControlFilter is active
2019-11-14 11:40:55.648  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.q.u.UriCrawlerTaskConfig           : URI Crawler task scheduled.
2019-11-14 11:40:56.626  WARN f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-11-14 11:40:59.163  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.f.ArrowheadFilter                  : PayloadSizeFilter is active
2019-11-14 11:40:59.329  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] .c.s.q.t.ProvidersReachabilityTaskConfig : Services end of validity task is not adjusted
2019-11-14 11:40:59.381  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] .c.s.q.t.ProvidersReachabilityTaskConfig : Providers reachabilitiy task is not adjusted
2019-11-14 11:41:02.892  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.ApplicationInitListener            : Core system name: SERVICE_REGISTRY
2019-11-14 11:41:02.894  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.ApplicationInitListener            : Server mode: SECURED
2019-11-14 11:41:03.034  INFO f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] e.a.c.ApplicationInitListener            : Server CN: service_registry.testcloud2.aitia.arrowhead.eu
2019-11-14 11:41:03.409 ERROR f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] o.a.c.u.LifecycleBase                    : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at eu.arrowhead.core.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistryMain.main(ServiceRegistryMain.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:239)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:213)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1202)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005)
    ... 22 more
2019-11-14 11:41:03.445  WARN f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase            : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-2 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.4/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2019-11-14 11:41:03.482 ERROR f75cd8bdc6c5 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I was thinking, that host networking mode would be the correct solution. I'd value all inputs.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried that via "environment" in docker-compose ?